# Cannot return new derived object from interface function

Tags: typescript, npm

Typescript code does not compile.

Compiler output:
error TS2416: Property 'deepcopy' in type 'Vector2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Vector'.

I just started using typescript yesterday and this seems like a trivial issue but cannot seem to find a proper solution to the problem.

```
interface Vector {
    deepcopy() : this;
}

export class Vector2 implements Vector {
    constructor() {
    }

    deepcopy() {
        return new Vector2();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or clues?

Comment: Have you tried `deepcopy(): Vector` in your interface?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Stackoverflow is wonderful! I had been scrambling around for an hour and I got a working answer within 10 mins! +10 votes for you man!

Comment: You are welcome. I added an answear so you can accept it in order to help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Vector {
    deepcopy() : Vector;
}

export class Vector2 implements Vector {
    constructor() {
    }

    deepcopy() {
        return new Vector2();
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that `this` is not a type. As a consequence `Vector2` does not match it. By changing it to `Vector` you can return your instance implementing the Vector interface as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in your particular scenario, but perhaps try using an `abstract class` instead:

```
export abstract class Vector {
  deepcopy(): this {
    return { ...this };
  }
}
export class Vector2 extends Vector {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  /* custom copy logic if necessary
  deepcopy(): this {
     ...
  }
  */
}
```

The following will be correctly typed:

```
const a = new Vector2(); // inferred type: Vector2
const b = a.deepcopy();  // inferred type: Vector2
```